# Code will not continue with datatable foreach

Tags: sql, asp.net, datatable

I have code that breaks the foreach and goes to the top and another foreach

It go trough the datatable 2 times as the batchsize says, and then go down and doing the restsharp, but after that it goes to the top and the foreach i have before the sql query.

Need it to do the batchsize part for all rows in the datatable

I can´t see what i have done wrong

Please help

This is my code:

```
 protected void run_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
     var body = "";
     var evenNums = new string[3] { "2", "3", "4" };
     var daytime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
     var day = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
     foreach (string Site in evenNums)
     {
         body = "{\"requestId\": \"144x25\",\"items\": [";


         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
         {
             string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection1"].ConnectionString;
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);
             string query = "SELECT [number],[surname],[forename],[emailAddress],[taxIdentifier] FROM[Customer]  WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE[CustomerID] IN(SELECT[CustomerID] FROM[Visit] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE[GamingDate] Between convert(Date, DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())) AND convert(Date, getdate())) AND(EmailAddress IS NOT NULL) AND(ContactTypes & 1 = 1) AND(HomePropertyID = " + Site + ") /*  2= Malmö  3=Göteborg  4=Stockholm  */ AND(LEN(TaxIdentifier) = '12')";
             SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
             conn.Open();
             comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
             DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

             using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
             {
                 adapter.Fill(dt1);
             }
             string csv = "";
             csv += "number" + "," + "\"surname\"" + "," + "\"forename\"" + "," + "\"repsonseId\"" + "," + "\"responseTime\"";

             string newFileName = "C:\\temp\\" + ort + "" + day + "FromNeon_Cleaned.csv";
             string clientHeader = "number" + "," + "\"surname\"" + "," + "\"forename\"" + "," + "\"repsonseId\"" + "," + "\"responseTime\"" + Environment.NewLine;
             File.WriteAllText(newFileName, clientHeader);

             int batchSize = 2;

             for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
             {
                 if (j == batchSize) { break; }
                 DataRow dtRow = dt1.Rows[j];

                 var number = dtRow.ItemArray[0];
                 var surname = dtRow.ItemArray[1];
                 var forename = dtRow.ItemArray[2];
                 var emailAddress = dtRow.ItemArray[3];
                 string taxidentifier = (string)dtRow.ItemArray[4];

                 if (Personnummer.Valid(taxidentifier))
                 {
                     body += "{\"itemId\": \"" + number + "\",\"subjectId\": \"" + taxidentifier + "\"},";
                 }
                 body = body.Remove(body.Length - 1);
                 body += "]}";
             }

             var url = "https://marketing.spelpaus.se/api/marketing-subjectid/mw41yZpBFC";
             var client = new RestClient(url);
             var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);
             request.AddHeader("authorization", "vGrpkoNEWHpMuQVrIKVGfsfx2l7SLbsSfQ7PbISjMyiK545ezHW5BzsfPgJq0HA6");
             request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

             request.AddBody(body, "application/json");
             RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
             if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
             {
                 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
                 var alloweditemsdata = (obj.allowedItemIds);
                 var responseId = (obj.responseId);

                 dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["number"] };
                 foreach (int alloweditem in alloweditemsdata)
                 {
                     DataRow Drw = dt1.Rows.Find(alloweditem);

                     var numberresult = Drw.ItemArray[0];
                     var surnameresult = Drw.ItemArray[1];
                     var forenameresult = Drw.ItemArray[2];
                     var emailAddressresult = Drw.ItemArray[3];
                     string taxidentifierresult = (string)Drw.ItemArray[4];
                     string clientDetails = " " + numberresult + ",\"" + surnameresult + "\",\"" + forenameresult + "\",\"" + emailAddressresult + "\",\"" + responseId + "\",\"" + daytime + "\"" + Environment.NewLine;
                     File.AppendAllText(newFileName, clientDetails, Encoding.Unicode);

                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

the code goes back to the top of the foreach (string Site in evenNums) loop, is likely due to the fact that you are breaking out of the loop using break when j reaches the batchSize. This causes the loop to exit prematurely, and control returns to the top of the foreach loop for the next site.

If you want the code to process all rows in the DataTable for each site, you should remove the break statement. Here's the relevant part of your code with the break statement removed:

```
int batchSize = 2;

for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    // Remove this 'if' condition to process all rows
    // if (j == batchSize) { break; }

    DataRow dtRow = dt1.Rows[j];

    // Rest of your code for processing each row...
}
```

Comment: I need the break i think
Because i need to take some at the time from the datatable
Batchsize is that who will control that